# Get affected triples from SPARQL update query

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I have a SPARQL update query like following

```
DELETE { ?s <http://ex#> <http://ex#OLD> }
INSERT { ?s <http://ex#> <http://ex#NEW> }
WHERE { ?s <http://ex#> <http://ex#OLD> }
```

I want to run this query on my model. This will result in deleting some triples and addition of some other triples in the model. I am looking for a way to get these affected triples in Apache jena.

Till now I have made a `ModelChangedListner` (https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/event-handler-howto.html) to get these triples. Even though it is working fine but the problem is that I want the affected triples before they are committed to the dataset. But the model changed listener does not provide any such guarantee.

**Edit:** If there is no solution in current version of Jena, I am open to modify and recompile the Jena code if someone can point me to the location where this modification should be made.

Comment: That update does not what you describe. `?o` is not in the WHERE part. Did you mean `DELETE { ?s <http://ex#> <http://ex#OLD> }`

Answer (score 2):

See [RDF Delta](https://afs.github.io/rdf-delta/) - specifically the `DatasetGraphChanges` - records changes to a dataset. It records the "add" and "delete" operations performed, recording the triples (quads) changed. Using a wrapper is more reliable and more general than `ModelChangedListener` because it captures the change operations on the basic storage (datasets).

Comment: I need to check more about RDF Delta but on first look it does not seem a match for my use case since I can not run another server. I tried other option of using DatasetGraphMonitor  but the problem is using UpdateAction.parseExecute(..) is not sending notifications. Maybe internally it is not using the wrapped dataset object passed.

Comment: Part of RDF Delta is the "rdf-patch" module which is a library, and not server dependent. DatasetGraphChanges is in that module.

Comment: Okay thanks I will explore it! But I still feel a native and reliable way to get the changes will be good because of more flexibility in terms of callbacks. 

And If UpdateAction.parseExecute(..) is not using the wrapped dataset object do you think underlying reason should be checked further..?

Comment: BTW thanks a lot for helping the community!